# Customize display number with Marker Clusterer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

As the attachment, clusterer display **417** markers in London.
I would like to custom a bit by thresholds. For example

- `<= 20: Display real number`
- `From 20 to 50: 20+`
- `From 50 to 100: 50+`
- `From 100 to 200: 100+`
- `> 200: 200+`
- etc

How do I apply thresholds to clusterer?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a wonderful way to change display number in clusterers. 
By change calculator method

```
markerCluster.setCalculator(new_cluster_calculator);

function new_cluster_calculator (markers, numStyles) {
  var index = 0;
  var title = "";
  var count = markers.length;
  var countStr = count.toString();

  var dv = countStr;
  while (dv !== 0) {
    dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
    index++;
  }

  index = Math.min(index, numStyles);

  if (count >= 200) {
    count = '200+';
  } else if (count >= 100) {
    count = '100+';
  } else if (count >= 50) {
    count = '50+';
  }

  return {
    text: count,
    index: index,
    title: title
  };
};
```